# Magento import tables from old database show error (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: magento-1.9, database

i want to import old customer data to new magento store i have imported all customer's table instead of customer_entity, when i import this table i am getting this error

## 1005 - Can't create table `test`.`customer_entity` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Please help me out for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error could be due to several reasons but you are working with imported tables so try checking ENGINE and/or CHARSET parameters: It can happen you are trying to add a new table using a different one!

From: [MySql - Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

> If you re-create a table that was dropped, it must have a definition that conforms to the foreign key constraints referencing it.

So if you are using a .sql file to import the customer's tables, open it and check it: at the end of queries there should be something like:

```
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

then be sure to use those same parameters for the new customer_entity table.

If the problem keep showing, check if foreign key column and the referencing have same column type or length, [read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11093174/5031164).

Reed also here [MariaDB: InnoDB foreign key constraint errors](https://mariadb.org/mariadb-innodb-foreign-key-constraint-errors/)